# distinctUntilChanged() on BehaviourSubject don't work

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular2-observables, behaviorsubject

My package.json:

- rxjs": "^5.5.6"
- @angular: "6.0.0-beta.5

`searchTextValueSubject` is a BehaviorSubject

```
import { debounceTime } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { distinctUntilChanged } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { pipe } from 'rxjs';

this.sharingVariableService
    .searchTextValueSubject
    .pipe(
        distinctUntilChanged((x, y) => {
            console.log(y.BarCodeS === x.BarCodeS);
            console.log(y.BarCodeS);
            console.log(x.BarCodeS);
            return y.BarCodeS === x.BarCodeS
        })
    )
    .subscribe((searchTextValue) => {
        this.searchTextValue = searchTextValue;
        this.getRessourceHardware(this.serverDataRessourceHardware._meta.max_results, this.searchTextValue);
    });
```

Result :

> true, 'd', 'd'
>
> true, 'da', 'da'

Expected :

> False, ' ', 'd'
>
> False, 'd', 'da'

I probably don't understand something. Could you please point me to the right direction ?

Comment: Hi Solinas, please note how I reformatted your source: it was _very_ hard to follow before, and wouldn't compile (it had an extra bracket, see the diff between edits, but I took the liberty to fix it because I take it as a copy/paste problem and not an actual bug since your code runs). Also note that while you (and I) want to write it "behaviour" with a "u" that is not the name of the operator.

Comment: thanks a lot, i'm new to stack overflow and gonna be more rigorous next time

Comment: Post a complete minimal example reproducing the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you might be sending mutated values to `searchTextValueSubject`.

Make sure your code is **not** doing something like this...

```
let value = {BarCodeS: 'd'}
this.sharingVariableService.searchTextValueSubject.next(value);

value.BarCodeS = 'da'; // wrong!
this.sharingVariableService.searchTextValueSubject.next(value);
```

The right way is this:

```
const value0 = {BarCodeS: 'd'}
this.sharingVariableService.searchTextValueSubject.next(value0);

const value1 = {...value0, BarCodeS: 'da'}; // right
this.sharingVariableService.searchTextValueSubject.next(value1);
```

Also note that the distinctUntilChanged comparer function is never called on the *first* emission (the first emission is necessarily distinct)